# Cannot use &dashUrl (type *[]byte) as type *string in assignment

Tags: go

I'm trying to parse a form post that may be empty and if it is I will change the variable.  Trying to use `*string` type.  The problem I'm having is it dosen't convert for the `dashUrl` but does for the `start_time`

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/base64"
    "strconv"
    "github.com/gocraft/web"
)

type YoutubeContext struct {
    StartTime *float64 `json:"start_time"`
    DashUrl   *string  `json:"dash_url"`
}

func (c *YoutubeContext) SetYoutubeContext(rw web.ResponseWriter, req *web.Request, next web.NextMiddlewareFunc) {
    if f, err := strconv.ParseFloat(req.FormValue("start_time"), 64); err == nil {
        c.StartTime = &f
    }
    if dashUrl, dashUrlDecodeErr := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(req.FormValue("dash_url")); dashUrlDecodeErr == nil {
        c.DashUrl = &dashUrl

    }

}
func main() {

}
```

the error it shows is this

`./test.go:19: cannot use &dashUrl (type *[]byte) as type *string in assignment`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Was helped in the gophers slack chat, need to make a temporary variable

```
blah := string(dashUrl)
c.DashUrl = &blah
```

Comment: You do not really need a temp variable, you just need a correct type: as the API docs say https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/base64/#Encoding.DecodeString `base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString` returns a `[]byte` slice and not a string.

Comment: right, but I'm trying to make it a pointer for later in the overall program if it's empty I change it.

Comment: The standard value for a byte slice is nil AFAIK, which is exactly what you are talking about, aren't you?

Comment: I suppose I am confused, I am not understanding, I know it returns a byte but I need a pointer string.

Comment: First, a string pointer is an antipattern in Go: the `string` class is lightweight even if it internally points to a massive chunk of data. Second, if you knew it returned a byte slice why did you give it a string pointer. And third, what you need is very subjective and not necessarily a good design: a `string` pointer is just as unnatural for a URL as is a byte slice -- you probably need a string in reality. Happy you found a solution though.

Comment: @OlegSklyar, a string pointer is the standard and idiomatic way to have a string that one can differentiate between and empty string and a zero value. It's heavily used in many APIs, I wouldn't start off calling it an anti-pattern.

Comment: @JimB "Slices, maps, channels, strings, function values, and interface values are implemented with pointers internally, and a pointer to them is often redundant." That sounds like a pattern to me and its opposite an anti-pattern. Now the fact that a pattern exists does not mean that there are no wide-spread exceptions. A good developer will consider what is best for the situation. Do you feel this was the case in the above example, is that field really optional to justify a nil pointer?

Comment: @OlegSklyar, if you need to differentiate between an empty string and an unset string, especially when dealing with APIs that require serialization, then yes, a `*string` is perfectly fine.

Comment: @OlegSklyar That's a big jump to accuse something of being an "anti-pattern" just because the practice is claimed as being "often redundant." It might be a code-smell, but that's not enough to call it an anti-pattern.